# Словарь на основе HashMap

Tags: java, коллекции, java-hashmap

Возникла необходимость создать класс словаря, метод которого для каждого слова возвращает его текстовое объяснение. Инициализировать словарь несколькими словами.
В данном варианте всегда возвращает `null`. Что я сделал не так?

```
pulic class Dict extends HashMap {
    HashMap<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String first;
    String second;

    public Dict(String first, String second) {
        dict.put(first, second);
    }

    public Dict() {}

    public void put(String first, String second) {
        dict.put(first, second);
    }

    public void printDict(String first) {
        System.out.println(dict.get(this.first));
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dict dict = new Dict();
        dict.put("я", "мы");
        dict.put("ты", "вы");
        dict.put("он, она, оно", "они");
        dict.printDict("я");
    }
}
```

Comment: Запись `HashMap<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String, String>();`, кстати, можно сократить до `HashMap<String, String> dict = new HashMap<>();`.

Comment: Ещё момент: использовать одновременно `extends HashMap` и `HashMap<String, String> dict` весьма странно. Если вам не нужно, чтобы `Dict` умел всё то же что и `HashMap`, то `extends HashMap` стоит убрать.

Comment: @Regent, А что если человек исподьзует java 6???

Comment: @BogdanK а на что это влияет в данном случае? Или вы про первый комментарий и diamond-оператор?

Comment: @Regent, я про diamond

Comment: @BogdanK тогда комментарий для него не будет полезен. Но почему-то мне кажется, что сейчас мало кто использует Java 6 (я сам каждый день использую ещё более старую и урезанную версию Java, но сегодня это, скорее, исключение, нежели обычное дело). Поэтому, на мой взгляд, для большинства (включая автора вопроса) комментарий будет полезен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю зачем вам поля `first` и `second`, ибо они никак не используются.
В методе `printDict` должно быть `dict.get(first)`: имеет смысл использовать переданный в метод параметр вместо неиспользуемого и неинициализированного поля.

```
public void printDict(String first)
{
    System.out.println(dict.get(first));
}
```